# Async Values to selectBox

Tags: angular

I am trying to assign a variable to my select-box, the values are coming async from the backend.
Tried to simulate a asynch-call with `setTimeout` and `setInterval`.

This is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7sbwfu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts).

How can I make the selectbox get working(like it would, if the data would have been there at the beginning) ?

Please provide a code-snippet.

Comment: does it help you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference of 'this' won't be available inside your setTimeout() method.

So if want to use regular function instead of arrow function you need to store / assign your ' this ' reference to some variable.

```
let this_ref = this
```

Then you can use 'this_ref' inside your setTimeout() method.

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fzuhqp?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

Or  if you want to use arrow function there, you don't need to store your 'this' reference.

```
setTimeout( () => {
    // your logic goes here
}, 3000)
```

Answer (score 2):

it's because you don't use an arrow function to do your setTimeout, if you declare it like this

```
setTimeout(function() {
//dummy
}, 3000);
```

you aren't in the angular context anymore, you need to do it like this :

```
setTimeout(() => {
//dummy
}, 3000);
```

stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4vvbcl?file=src/app/hello.component.ts